# Calculate return for a set of securities downloaded using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, portfolio

I downloaded adjusted closing price using quantmod for a set of securities. I want to calculate daily/weekly/monthly return for all securities. Usual dailyReturn, weeklyReturn etc not working. What do I need to do? Here is my code.

```
tickers <- c('FB','MMM')
data_env <- new.env()
getSymbols(Symbols = tickers, env = data_env)
tempPort <- do.call(merge, eapply(data_env, Ad))

head(tempPort )
           MMM.Adjusted FB.Adjusted
2007-01-03     57.00983          NA
2007-01-04     56.78401          NA
2007-01-05     56.39790          NA
2007-01-08     56.52174          NA
2007-01-09     56.58731          NA
2007-01-10     56.71116          NA

head(weeklyReturn(tempPort,  type = 'log', leading=TRUE))
           weekly.returns
2012-05-18   -0.010791856
2012-05-25    0.015093078
2012-06-01   -0.023027534
2012-06-08    0.037315263
2012-06-15    0.016605617
2012-06-22   -0.007000966
```

I want data with returns for MMM and FB in two different columns. In my actual problem I have 50+ tickers. Hence calculating returns individually is not a solution.

Comment: you do have data in different column. The only issue is since the `index` (dates) do not match you have got lot of `NA`s there for `FB.Adjusted`. If you scroll down sufficiently you'll see the data for `FB.Adjusted`. What do you expect as your final output?

Comment: FB started trading in 2012 so the first 5 years will be NA. You can do everything with lapply calls to get everything in a big list instead of a different environment. But as @RonakShah asked, what is your expected output?

Comment: I expect to see three columns - Date, MMM Return, FB Return. Starting from 2007-01-03. First row would be NA for both. Second row would have return for MMM and NA for FB. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a loop as such:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

prices <- list()
returns <- list()

for(i in 1:length(tickers)) {
  getSymbols(tickers[i], adjusted = TRUE, output.size = "full")

  prices[[i]] <- Ad(get(tickers[i])) # Gets the adjusted close column
  ret         <- Return.calculate(Ad(get(tickers[i])), method = "log")
  returns[[i]]   <- ret # Adds return calculation to the list

}
```

Also consider using the alpha vantage api. You would need to go to their site and get an api key, and set `source='av'` in the getSymbols() function call.

Then, merge your data afterwords like this:

```
returns <- do.call(cbind, returns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quantmod add-in package `qmao` which has a built-in `RF` (stands for `return frame`) which does what you want. Assuming you have downloaded `FB` and `AMZN` this is the line to use:

```
library(qmao)    
rets <- RF(c(‘FB’,’AMZN’), silent = TRUE, type = ‘discrete )

> tail(rets)
                  FB      AMZN
2019-05-10 -0.001643 -0.005206
2019-05-13 -0.036105 -0.035609
2019-05-14 -0.004462  0.009568
2019-05-15  0.030654  0.016863
2019-05-16  0.003865  0.019464
2019-05-17 -0.009038 -0.020219
```

Have a look at `?RF` to check the available argument options.